# Prevent Non-SELECT SQL Statements

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm allowing users to input their own SQL statement to execute, but only if it's a SELECT statement. Is there a way to detect if the SQL statement is anything but this, i.e. an ALTER, INSERT, DROP, etc.? I'll worry about other concerns such as a query locking up a table and such later, but this is more of a proof of concept right now. I can restrict the service account on the server running the app to have read-only rights on the db, but I'm interested in seeing it handled in the app.

This is my approach to it by detecting the first word of the query, but this seems vulnerable. Is there a cleaner way to do this detection?

```
public void ExecuteQuery(string connectionString, int id)
{
    //The SQL statement will be user input
    var sql = "SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC FROM MyTable where MyTableId = @Id";
    var split = sql.Split(' ');

    if (split[0].ToUpper() != "SELECT") Console.WriteLine("Only use a SELECT statement.");
    else
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value = id;
            connection.Open();

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{reader["ColumnA"]}, {reader["ColumnB"]}, 
                                       {reader["ColumnC"]}");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
            }

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wrap the whole thing in a `TransactionScope` and never commit so that no matter what they do, any DML will be rolled back.

Comment: Can you manage user permissions on the SQL Server? Because whatever account is executing the SQL you should only grant SELECT permissions. I think this would be the prefered solution over your proposed solution or any "code" based solution.

Comment: Why are you allowing users to create their own sql statements? This is just a really bad idea. select * from sys.columns, sys.columns, sys.columns and your whole system is crippled for hours. For me the proof of concept should be why to never allow this type of application anywhere near a sql database.

Comment: Can I just say that allowing users to directly pass SQL statements to your database is a really bad idea. A poorly written SQL statement (even if it is just a SELECT) can bring your server to its knees.

Comment: And trying to look at the first word of the query...not good. /*select*/drop table ... It is just WAY too easy to get around systems that check the contents of the string.

Comment: Setting a short `CommandTimeout` will help with concerns presented here if you really have a legitimate business need to allow this.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm aware of the risks and this is more of a "sandbox" question than anything. This will never end up available to a user, just a concept I wanted to try. String parsing is exactly why I asked this since it's a terrible route to go, but I wanted to see if there's a cleaner in-code way of doing it.

Comment: And resource governor could cap the resource usage as well if you're on Enterprise Editon. If you are going to do this you should just do it through permissions. Any other scheme likely can be bypassed.

Comment: @SimonGates Yep, I could definitely manage user permissions for it. I was just interested in seeing if there was a clean in-code solution. Definitely looks like there isn't so I'll go about it on the permission level!

Comment: @Crowcoder Even in a transaction scope there's nothing stopping the SQL calling commit itself until `@@trancount` reaches 0.

Comment: @MartinSmith good point.

Comment: sql-server is my favorite, because it is so hackable: `SELECT A FROM X; DROP X;  DROP Y;  DROP Z; PRINT  PRINT N'You have been hacked!';`

Comment: @RyanIntravia I think so - you can then sleep easy at night :) i've added my thoughts on how you should go about this.

Comment: @MikeNakis but not only limited to SQL Server of course :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would scrap any attempt at trying to manage this in application code. Instead use SQL Server.

A good way to manage things is to do the following.

1. Create a New Schema.
2. Create a Database Role, the role should own the schema.
3. Create Views over the tables you want to expose even if they are 1:1 they should be in the Schema.
4. Add the service account to the Role.

The service account can only SELECT from the view and you have absolute control of what you are exposing and what data they can SELECT.

This is easily searchable / auditable even for other developers and DBA's. It also gives you a great view of the impact of any schema changes.

Comment: This won't work as written. If the role owns the schema and someone else owns the base objects then the ownership chain will be broken and permissions will still be needed on the base objects.

Comment: Accepting this since it's a way of not handling it in code and a better approach. I'll manage the permissions a little differently, but this is preferred over in-app. Thanks!